# Why are latitude not part of the UTM system?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, latitude-longitude, utm

I am trying to project long/lat coordinates to UTM in R (actually I have a script that works) but I'm curious about the zone argument. Here is the script I have. It uses the `spTransform`function from the `sp`package.

```
spTransform(xy, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=20 ellps=WGS84"))
```

I was wondering why the zone argument only accepts a number and not a combination of number and letter like in the military version of UTM (such as 20S or 20U for example). I was under the impression that a projection accurately reflects the real distances between points only if it's on a restricted area but it seems I could project points from Antarctica to Greenland and not need to specify more the area I am interested in. Does the function automatically adjust using the latitude given. Then why doesn't it do the same with longitude?

Comment: First off, the Military Grid Reference System (MGRS) is *not* "the military version of UTM" -- it's a mapping system *based on* the Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM) projection, which slices the globe into 6 degree wedges. The UTM projection only has zone and south or north for parameters (though you could conceivably make 6-degree slices *not* offset on 177W,171W,...,177E). In practice, the military *doesn't* use UTM for  latitudes near the poles, preferring a polar stereographic for those regions (which is also a component of MGRS).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PROJ strings to set the CRS of a spatial object, you just need to add the `"+south"` argument to define the UTM zone in the southern hemisphere. Nonetheless, if your data is in the southern hemisphere and you project it into a UTM zone in the northern hemisphere, the data will still be in the southern hemisphere, but far away from the coordinates for which the corresponding UTM zone was designed for. Here is an example.

```
# UTM 20S
xy2 = spTransform(xy, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=20 +south ellps=WGS84"))
# UTM 20N
xy3 = spTransform(xy, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=20 ellps=WGS84"))
```

Finally, you might want to check the `sf` package for working with spatial data in vector format.

Comment: Thank for your answer Jonathan. If I understand correctly, the default hemisphere is the northern hemisphere. I still don't really get why you don't need to be more specific regarding the latitude though. Is it that on the North to South axis, the projection does not distort the distances between points and it only does on the East-West axis ? Also, do you have a specific reason in mind I should work with vector format in particular rather than SpatialPointsDataFrames ?